# Visual force page not being displayed in layout

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, page-layout

Hello I have a page which holds two components , one is a JavaScript calendar and another is an array calendar. now I have added this page to opportunity layout. but the problem is the page is not being displayed on layout but i could able to open it directly.

Comment: Is it not visible or any error? may the change in size(ht/width) would make it work.

Comment: Please check the layout to which you have added the VF Page and the layout assigned to your profile.Just a guess that the added layout could be different

Comment: Should check the console for any JavaScript errors. Sometimes there are conflicts due to having multiple versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the page in opportunity layout add an Opportunity Object as a Standard Controller in Apex Page

```xml
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="yourController">
```

then go to Opportunity page layout add the visualForce page that you want.

Comment: You do not need a docType for adding page to standard layout, standardController is enough.

Comment: Yeah you're right and I didn't ever said  that docType is required for the solution.